# How to update column by insert sub query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am updating table column by subquery... but subquery happens to be insert expression which isn't valid syntax.

So how to do this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = (
  INSERT otherTable (otherColumn)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID 
  VALUES ('foo')
)
```

Which is from functional point of view ≈equal to valid query:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = (
  Select ot.ID
  From otherTable ot
  where ot.otherColumn = table.anotherOne
)
```

Comment: Clearly they are not equivalent, because one is valid syntax and the other is not.  You can use two separate queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah subquery isn't indeed hard limit but I am using this with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 where I can't get any return value from SQL expression.

But let me reprhase: From _expression_return_value_structure_ point of view they are exactly equal and therefore query I wrote makes sense. Therefore I expect you as a human understand it meaning or please explain why it's conceptually wrong.

Comment: Is "~equal" in any way similar to [Bitwise NOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/equals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: @HABO I meant "approximately".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a concept of [Composable DML](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/2009/04/08/composable-dml/) in SQL Server. This allows syntax like

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT O.ID
FROM 
 (
  INSERT otherTable (otherColumn)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID 
  VALUES ('foo')
 )  O
WHERE O.ID <> 1
```

but it is very limited and does not allow chaining the `OUTPUT` clause to another `UPDATE`.

The error message if you try

```
UPDATE table0
SET column0 = ( 
SELECT O.ID
FROM 
 (
  INSERT otherTable (otherColumn)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID 
  VALUES ('foo')
 )  O
)
```

is

> A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in
>   a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an
>   INSERT statement.

You would need to capture the results of the `OUTPUT` clause in a table variable and use that in the `UPDATE`.

Or possibly just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if `inserted.ID` is an `IDENTITY` column and you are always inserting a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an update with a join.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.[column] = ot.Id
FROM [table] t
    JOIN [otherTable] ot
        ON ot.otherColumn = t.anotherone;
```

Comment: This is essentially reformation of my second example which works and is NOT what I am trying to do. Essence is to create new row to otherTable for every existing table and make connection by foreign key. Or did I miss somthing? =)